# Run Through A List Then Paste Result To Its Next Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to create a macro wherein it would go through all the list of websites in column J starting at row 2 (header at row 1). Get the information that I want from each website, then display them in column K, which is right next to the websites where the information was taken from.
The only problem is that, I cant make the macro go to each of the websites.
I dont know what is wrong with the code.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim sdd As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim html As Object
    Dim mylinks As Object
    Dim mylink As Object
    Dim result As String

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, "J").Value

    ' Hide InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    ie.navigate myURL

    ' Loop until page fully loads
    Do While ie.readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    ' Information i want to get from the URLs
    sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("timeline-text")(0).innerText

    ' Format the result
    add = Split(sdd, "$")
    Range("K3") = add(1)

    ' Close InternetExplorer
    ie.Quit

    'Return to Normal?
    ie.Visible = True
    End
    Next
    ' Clean up
    Set ie = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

$85,100 is the information I want to get from one of the URLs.

```
<span class="font-size-base font-normal">Est.</span>
<span itemprop="price" content="85100">$85,100</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quit IE until you've completed the loop. Simply navigate to the next URL and record the new page's information on the same row as the URL was collected from.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sdd As String, myURL As String, result As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim ie As Object, html As Object, mylinks As Object, mylink As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' Hide InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow

        'collect next web page url
        myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, "J").Value

        ' URL to get data from
        ie.navigate myURL

        ' Loop until page fully loads
        Do While ie.readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            'allow other process through the message queue
            DoEvents
        Loop

        ' Information i want to get from the URLs
        sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("timeline-text")(0).innerText

        ' Format the result
        add = Split(sdd, "$")
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "K") = add(1)

    Next i

    'Return to Normal?
    ie.Visible = True
    ' Close InternetExplorer
    ie.Quit
    ' Clean up
    Set ie = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

I've also added `DoEvents` within your page load wait loop. This allows other processes to execute instead of tying up resources in the single threaded VBA process.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I must have missed something with my explanation. Column J has a list of websites, starting at J2. Let's say it would go all the way down to J10. From each website, there is a certain information I want to get, so the macro will visit the website at J2, get that information and paste it in K2, then visit the website in J3, paste that information in K3, and so on. I already have an existing list of website at column J, which also happens to be dynamic.

Comment: Your code was putting the `add(1)` value into column I so I used that. Change `Sheet1.Cells(i, "I")` to `Sheet1.Cells(i, "K")`.

Comment: Though its putting the information that I need to the right column, but its only doing that for 1 row. The rest of the list are left out.

Comment: My bad. I just went over your code again and realized you had a rogue `End` command that terminated the loop on the first iteration. I've removed it above.

Comment: Wow! That really does the job! Amazing! Thank you so much. Just one follow up question though. The `timeline-text` isn't return any information for some of the link, so I think it's not being used by all of the links. Maybe I can use something from the one stated below since I have found out that it exists on all of the links?

`<span class="font-size-base font-normal">Est.</span>`
`<span itemprop="price" content="85100">`

Comment: Yes, there are functions that pick out the values from custom attributes in html tags.

Comment: I'm currently searching the internet as this is not working `sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("font-size-base font-normal").getelementsbyclassname("span")(0).innerText` nor`sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("font-size-base font-normal").getelementsbytagname("span")(0).innerText`

Comment: I think you need something to do with *vba queryselector attribute*

Comment: You are right. Im in the middle of searching the internet and found out that XML and queryselector is better than IE as it is much faster. I also tested it and it works with `sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("font-size-base font-normal").getAttribute("content")(0).innerText` . Now the only challenge left is how to make it work through a list like how I describe the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is something you have to take note of while programming. Always try to echo a visible result.

Do this before the loop after the lastrow
`msgbox lastrow`
E.g in between the for loop, do something like
`msgbox sdd`
You should be able to get where the errors lie.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I always use F8 to check on the results per line, I dont like msgbox to show me the result. Maybe its just me as I somehow see it as a restriction to how I want the results to be in this case.